# Dijkstra's Dilema: How can I make my Algorithm abstract?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

I was doing code forces and wanted to implement Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm for a directed graph using Java with an Adjacency Matrix, but I'm having difficulty making it work for other sizes than the one it is coded to handle.

Here is my working code

```
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;//substitute for infinity

    int[][] points={//I used -1 to denote non-adjacency/edges
            //0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
            {-1,20,-1,80,-1,-1,90,-1},//0
            {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1},//1
            {-1,-1,-1,10,-1,50,-1,20},//2
            {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,20,-1},//3
            {-1,50,-1,-1,-1,-1,30,-1},//4
            {-1,-1,10,40,-1,-1,-1,-1},//5
            {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},//6
            {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1} //7
            };
    int [] record = new int [8];//keeps track of the distance from start to each node
    Arrays.fill(record,max);
    int sum =0;int q1 = 0;int done =0;
    ArrayList<Integer> Q1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();//nodes to transverse 
    ArrayList<Integer> Q2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();//nodes collected while transversing
    Q1.add(0);//starting point
    q1= Q1.get(0);
    while(done<9) {// <<< My Problem
        for(int q2 = 1; q2<8;q2++) {//skips over the first/starting node
            if(points[q1][q2]!=-1) {//if node is connected by an edge
                if(record[q1] == max)//never visited before
                    sum=0;
                else 
                    sum=record[q1];//starts from where it left off
                int total = sum+points[q1][q2];//total distance of route
                if(total < record[q2])//connected node distance
                    record[q2]=total;//if smaller
                Q2.add(q2);//colleceted node
            }
        }
        done++;
        Q1.remove(0);//removes the first node because it has just been used
        if(Q1.size()==0) {//if there are no more nodes to transverse
            Q1=Q2;//Pours all the collected connecting nodes to Q1
            Q2= new ArrayList<Integer>();
            q1=Q1.get(0);
        }
        else//
            q1=Q1.get(0);//sets starting point 
    }![enter image description here][1]
```

However, my version of the algorithm only works because I set the while loop to the solved answer. So in other words, it only works for this problem/graph because **I solved it by hand first**.

## How could I make it so it works for all groups of all sizes?

Here is the pictorial representation of the example graph my problem was based on:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main answer you are looking for is that you should let the while-loop run until Q1 is empty. What you're doing is essentially a best-first search. There are more changes required though, since your code is a bit unorthodox.

Commonly, Dijkstra's algorithm is used with a priority queue. Q1 is your "todo list" as I understand from your code. The specification of Dijkstra's says that the vertex that is closest to the starting vertex should be explored next, so rather than an ArrayList, you should use a PriorityQueue for Q1 that sorts vertices according to which is closest to the starting vertex. The most common Java implementation uses the `PriorityQueue` together with a tuple class: An internal class which stores a reference to a vertex and a "distance" to the starting vertex. The specification for Dijkstra's also specifies that if a new edge is discovered that makes a vertex closer to the start, the DecreaseKey operation should then be used on the entry in the priority queue to make the vertex come up earlier (since it is now closer). However, since `PriorityQueue` doesn't support that operation, a completely new entry is just added to the queue. If you have a good implementation of a heap that supports this operation (I made one myself, [here](https://github.com/Ghostkeeper/hattusa/blob/master/src/net/dulek/collections/PairingHeap.java)) then decreaseKey can significantly increase efficiency as you won't need to create those tuples any more either then.

So I hope that is a sufficient answer then: Make a proper 'todo' list instead of Q1, and to make the algorithm generic, let that while-loop run until the todo list is empty.

Edit: I made you an implementation based on your format, that seems to work:

```
public void run() {
    final int[][] points = { //I used -1 to denote non-adjacency/edges
        //0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
        {-1,20,-1,80,-1,-1,90,-1}, //0
        {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1}, //1
        {-1,-1,-1,10,-1,50,-1,20}, //2
        {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,20,-1}, //3
        {-1,50,-1,-1,-1,-1,30,-1}, //4
        {-1,-1,10,40,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //5
        {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}, //6
        {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}  //7
    };
    final int[] result = dijkstra(points,0);
    System.out.print("Result:");
    for(final int i : result) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }
}

public int[] dijkstra(final int[][] points,final int startingPoint) {
    final int[] record = new int[points.length]; //Keeps track of the distance from start to each vertex.
    final boolean[] explored = new boolean[points.length]; //Keeps track of whether we have completely explored every vertex.
    Arrays.fill(record,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    final PriorityQueue<VertexAndDistance> todo = new PriorityQueue<>(points.length); //Vertices left to traverse.
    todo.add(new VertexAndDistance(startingPoint,0)); //Starting point (and distance 0).
    record[startingPoint] = 0; //We already know that the distance to the starting point is 0.
    while(!todo.isEmpty()) { //Continue until we have nothing left to do.
        final VertexAndDistance next = todo.poll(); //Take the next closest vertex.
        final int q1 = next.vertex;
        if(explored[q1]) { //We have already done this one, don't do it again.
            continue; //...with the next vertex.
        }

        for(int q2 = 1;q2 < points.length;q2++) { //Find connected vertices.
            if(points[q1][q2] != -1) { //If the vertices are connected by an edge.
                final int distance = record[q1] + points[q1][q2];
                if(distance < record[q2]) { //And it is closer than we've seen so far.
                    record[q2] = distance;
                    todo.add(new VertexAndDistance(q2,distance)); //Explore it later.
                }
            }
        }

        explored[q1] = true; //We're done with this vertex now.
    }
    return record;
}

private class VertexAndDistance implements Comparable<VertexAndDistance> {
    private final int distance;
    private final int vertex;

    private VertexAndDistance(final int vertex,final int distance) {
        this.vertex = vertex;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    /**
     * Compares two {@code VertexAndDistance} instances by their distance.
     * @param other The instance with which to compare this instance.
     * @return A positive integer if this distance is more than the distance
     * of the specified object, a negative integer if it is less, or
     * {@code 0} if they are equal.
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final VertexAndDistance other) {
        return Integer.compare(distance,other.distance);
    }
}
```

Output: `0 20 40 50 2147483647 30 70 60`